# CSS Image Sprites vs. UI Fonts for Social Icons - From a Page Load Speed Perspective

Tags: css, fonts, sprite, page-load-time

I am curious about the pros and cons of using a CSS image sprite for my social media icons vs. using a custom UI font.

Which one will offer superior performance in terms of page load speed?

It seems to me that a CSS sprite may be better- as there is only a single HTTP request & the file size can probably be kept smaller than a custom UI font for social icons.

Anyone have insight on this?

Answer (score 4):

One of the two techniques will have a slight '*superior performance in terms of page load speed*', but most of the time project requirements and development time far more important than load speed.

### *Image sprite* vs *Icon font* and page load speed

**Number of requests:** Both techniques need CSS and load one file. You need to generate multiple fonts, but only one font is requested and used.

**Amount of CSS:** More or less the same. @font-face is more initial code but less applying the icon.

**File size:** More or less the same, but depends on icon size. Bigger icons need bigger image sprite. Fonts use vectors and will stay the same size. I looked up a font with 300 glyphs it is a 25KB WOFF (the SVG is double the size). A font containing one glyph is 4KB. To compare the two I should render all glyphs black on transparent in a sprite. But at what icon size?

**Render speed:** Negligible.

**Cache:** Negligible. There are CDNs for icon fonts.

I think both techniques score the same. The differences are negligible. Off course one will be slightly faster than the other. But you should measure that in your specific situation. Anyway, we know multiple requests are the bottleneck. And both fonts and sprites only need one request.

### *Image sprite* vs *Icon font* and stuff that matters!

**Color:** Sprites can use all RGBA colors in the same icons. Fonts only have one color. You can apply effects to make fonts more special (and these effects will match the same effects on other page elements).

**Shape / size:** Image sprites need duplicate icons if you want to apply different sized icons (e.g. high resolution displays). Fonts can be applied in any size.

**Rendering:** Image sprites render pixel perfect. Fonts get applied by render engines, resulting in differences per platform. Windows utilizes the built in hinting instructions. Creating good hinting requires a lot of skill.

**Use area:** Image sprites can also be used by other page elements (backgrounds). Since fonts are applied as text, they have a smaller use area.

**Maintainability:** The icons need to be one pixel bigger. This kind of change makes you generate the sprites and update CSS. With a font changing just one font-size value will get the job done.

**Development time:** Above points are important design decisions when creating your own icons. That said, most developers just use the technique they feel comfortable with. Or pick one of the may sprites or fonts out there.

To come back to your question. Do you want to use multiple colors in a single image? Than an image sprite is the way to go. I would include each icon as separate Base64 image. It keeps maintenance easy. Although this will come at a cost: Very roughly, the final size of Base64-encoded binary data is equal to 1.37 times the original data size + 814 bytes (for headers).

I'm curious what your considerations are. Looking forward to your comments!

Comment: You're losing _a lot_ by using separate images for the icon. Taking Simplicons' Arrows/Navigation as an example, because I have it handy: 72 grayscale 32x32 icons, total size 228558 byte. Arranging it into a 320x256 sprite: 31928 byte. (Multiply by 1.33 to account for base64.)

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz: Thanks, I updated my answer and mentioned the costs of base64.

Comment: In web development you have eg. zoom in css, so you don't have to create sprites in many resolutions, problem is when you zoom it so big, user see all icon defects.

Answer (score 0):

**1) Icon Font glyphs are going to render faster than image sprites.**

**2) An Icon Font can also be smaller in `k` size than a comparable sprite sheet** if you use [Fontello](http://fontello.com/) (free, and easy to use) to create a custom font that only includes the glyphs you are going to use in your app / site.

For example, for a recent project I created a TrueType font that contains 8 glyphs, weighs *less than 8kb*, and the icons scale beautifully up or down; sharp and clear.

Easily apply colors, try 80% opacity, etc.

Comment: Regarding 1) Is this true? If you are going to change the icon on the fly, then I would expect the opposite! Copying a different part of an already loaded bitmap must be less processor-intensive than redrawing a font glyph, with all the vectors, but I am guessing. Do you have any metrics?

Answer (score -1):

Css sprites do improve on load times but with the speed of the internet the average viewer would never even notice the difference. This website has a full breakdown of what they are and what they do, comparisons and more. http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Hope this helps :)

Comment: That's great and all, but it doesn't answer the question, which is asking for a comparison between sprite sheets and font images.

Comment: It's not just about bandwidth, as the OP mentions, the biggest driver for the use of sprites is minimizing the number of requests, which is significant since most browsers will cap simultaneous requests at a pretty low number (I've read before it's around 6).

Comment: The article offers a comparison on performance showing that the images send 10 Http requests at a total size of 20.5kb where as the sprites send only 1 http request at a file size of 13kb

from what I'm understanding of your question that is the comparison that you were after? if not please clarify and I will be happy to provide more information.

Comment: I did @Daedalus but I believe that I am not fully understanding the question. This may be more helpful then the previous link (provided I got it right this time) if not then I apologise.

http://www.jontetzlaff.com/blog/2013/04/29/image-sprites-vs-web-icon-fonts/

Comment: Down vote. Every millisecond counts; especially now in 2015 when Google says over half it's global queries come from mobile devices. Unsubstantiated generalizations about "speed of the internet" and "average viewer" don't make sense in the studied context of asset delivery optimization.